# Creating a file from Zapier

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, zapier

Thanks in advance for the help. I am trying to create a file using Zapier. I have base64 data that is an MP3 and I would like to use zapier to either create the file and store it on Google Drive or something or create an html file with an "audio" tag and store that on Google Drive.

I have tried everything I can think of including using the Google Drive action to create a text file and then calling the Google API and trying to change the mime type and file extension, but I cannot change the mime type without uploading another version of the file - per Google's API restrictions.

I also tried several ideas to create the file using the Zapier code module, but since you cannot import, I cannot find a way to do this.

I have also searched all the other Zapier apps to try and think of something clever and I cannot come up with anything.

I am basically trying to rig up a solution where I would type something into slack, have it sent to Google's TTS API, retrieve the Base64 response, and then turn that into either an html file containing the or audio tag which the browser will handle or a sound file, either of which I can then post a link to within the Slack channel I originally posted from.

Anyway, I feel like this should be pretty simple but I am hitting dead ends everywhere and would appreciate any ideas :)

Thanks.

JJO

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. That's a great question!

My recommendation would be to use the [Zapier CLI](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) to create a private app for your own use. It would have a single action (`Create File`) and has access to the entire npm ecosystem. You could send that data wherever you wanted, so there's a lot of flexibility there. I don't have much experience with your specific issue, but there are few problems a javascript app sort out.

Hope that points you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks David! Unfortunately creating a CLI is beyond my capability so I'll have to look into that and get back to the thread once I try it. Good idea though :)

Comment: @xavdid Are there any complete examples on how to work with files in Zapier in this way? I'm looking at the files example on Github, using hydrate / dehydrate, but I'm not really able to tell how to connect this to the base64 use-case.

The idea is that a base64 file content string is sent to the Zap with a hook and needs to be converted to a file within the Zap. Then it should be passed on to a file storage app, like Dropbox or similar. I can create a `Buffer` with the file content but I'm not sure if that is enough to pass the file forward or if there is some other approach.

Thanks!